# Adding form elements do not update the default text inside an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a beautiful form for selecting multiple files for upload in Bootstrap. The problem is that when I add a second file, the default text inside the button stops from updating. What am I missing?

```
<div class="control-group" id="fields">
   <div class="controls">
      <div class="entry input-group uploads">

         <label class="file-upload btn">
         Choose file from computer...<input  name="fields[]" type="file" />
         </label>

         <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn btn-upload-add" type="button">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
         </button>
         </span>

      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What should happen: when I click the plus button and choose a second file, the second title should also update, and not only the first one. The complete work is here: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/djgn1072/)